# MongoDB Performance with Unwind and Aggregate

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to improve a query to return the count of each item inside my array ("Facets").
Other queries looks fine.

Edit : Adding 3 sample documents:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5bab1d5e2172eda710338c5c"), 
"SiteID" : "VR_1038936695_1", 
"PriceSale" : 580000.0, 
"Title" : "Apartamento a Venda em Salvador, Pituba, 4 dormitórios, 2 suítes, 4 banheiros, 2 vagas", 
"Description" : "Apartamento 44 dormitórios (sendo 2 suítes), banheiros, 2 garagens, dependência de empregada, sala integrada à varanda.andar alto, 119 mº. Condomínio com infraestrutura completa: Piscina, quadra poliesportiva, academia, salão de festas, brinquedoteca, parque infantil, salão de jogos, playground com bastante área. Localização: Próximo ao Hiper Ideal, escolas, faculdade, Mini Shopping, etc... <br> <br> OPORTUNIDADE!!! <br> <br> Agende Sua Visita!!! <br> <br> <br> - Ar Condicionado <br> - Móveis Planejados <br> - Portão Eletrônico <br> - Área de Serviço <br> - Cozinha <br> - Bares e Restaurantes <br> - Escola <br> - Farmácia <br> - Shopping Center <br> - Supermercado", 
"Link" : "https://www.vivareal.com.br/imovel/apartamento-4-quartos-pituba-bairros-salvador-com-garagem-119m2-venda-RS580000-id-1038936695/", 
"QtyRoomsMin" : 4.0, 
"QtyRoomsMax" : 4.0, 
"QtySuitesMin" : 2.0, 
"QtySuitesMax" : 2.0, 
"QtyParkingSlotMin" : 2.0, 
"QtyParkingSlotMax" : 2.0, 
"AreaMin" : 119.0, 
"AreaMax" : 119.0, 
"QtyBathroomsMin" : 4.0, 
"QtyBathroomsMax" : 4.0, 
"SiteOrigin" : NumberInt(3), 
"Type" : NumberInt(1), 
"Subtype" : NumberInt(7), 
"UpdateDate" : ISODate("2018-10-24T00:00:51.553+0000"), 
"SortOrder" : NumberInt(280), 
"IdDistrict" : NumberInt(1876), 
"DistrictName" : "Pituba", 
"IdCity" : NumberInt(988), 
"CityName" : "Salvador", 
"IdState" : NumberInt(5), 
"StateName" : "Bahia", 
"UF" : "BA", 
"FullAddress" : "Rua Ceará", 
"ZipCode" : NumberInt(41830450), 
"Latitude" : null, 
"Longitude" : null, 
"ImageUrl" : "https://resizedimgs.vivareal.com/crop/360x240/vr.images.sp/7ff41293883888840d992d9832e7c542.jpg", 
"IdTransaction" : NumberInt(1), 
"ExpireAt" : ISODate("2018-11-12T23:00:51.553+0000"), 
"Facets" : [
    "Academia", 
    "Ar Condicionado", 
    "Área de Serviço", 
    "Cozinha", 
    "Espaço Verde / Parque", 
    "Piscina", 
    "Quadra Poliesportiva", 
    "Salão de jogos", 
    "Garagem"
]
}

{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5bbb1ea72172eda710cfb6ff"), 
"SiteID" : "VR_56466679_1", 
"PriceSale" : 610000.0, 
"Title" : "LINDO APARTAMENTO , VENHA CONHECER!!", 
"Description" : "IMPERDÍVEL. CHARME E BOM GOSTO. EXCELENTE LOCALIZAÇÃO. LINDO APARTAMENTO. PERTO DE TUDO. TODOS OS AMBIENTES COM PLANEJADOS , SALA PARA 2 AMBIENTES ,BANHEIROS COM BOX DE VIDRO , TETO REBAIXADO COM NOVA ILUMINAÇÃO E FIAÇÃO ELETRICA", 
"Link" : "https://www.vivareal.com.br/imovel/apartamento-3-quartos-vila-regente-feijo-zona-leste-sao-paulo-com-garagem-83m2-venda-RS610000-id-56466679/", 
"QtyRoomsMin" : 3.0, 
"QtyRoomsMax" : 3.0, 
"QtySuitesMin" : 1.0, 
"QtySuitesMax" : 1.0, 
"QtyParkingSlotMin" : 2.0, 
"QtyParkingSlotMax" : 2.0, 
"AreaMin" : 83.0, 
"AreaMax" : 83.0, 
"QtyBathroomsMin" : 2.0, 
"QtyBathroomsMax" : 2.0, 
"SiteOrigin" : NumberInt(3), 
"Type" : NumberInt(1), 
"Subtype" : NumberInt(7), 
"UpdateDate" : ISODate("2018-10-14T15:21:11.618+0000"), 
"SortOrder" : NumberInt(689), 
"IdDistrict" : NumberInt(42984), 
"DistrictName" : "Vila Regente Feijó", 
"IdCity" : NumberInt(9668), 
"CityName" : "São Paulo", 
"IdState" : NumberInt(26), 
"StateName" : "São Paulo", 
"UF" : "SP", 
"FullAddress" : "Rua Água Rasa - 83", 
"ZipCode" : NumberInt(3343010), 
"Latitude" : null, 
"Longitude" : null, 
"ImageUrl" : "https://resizedimgs.vivareal.com/crop/360x240/vr.images.sp/d06c1ae285d789baa4fc8661656dbe4a.jpg", 
"IdTransaction" : NumberInt(1), 
"ExpireAt" : ISODate("2018-10-29T15:21:11.618+0000"), 
"Facets" : [
    "Espaço Verde / Parque", 
    "Academia", 
    "Área de Serviço", 
    "Garagem", 
    "Salão de Festas", 
    "Piscina", 
    "Quadra Poliesportiva"
]
}

{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5bbb51d82172eda710db154c"), 
"SiteID" : "VR_1037226651_1", 
"PriceSale" : 2990000.0, 
"Title" : "Apartamento em São Paulo", 
"Description" : "Lindo(a) Apartamento de 278,44 m² no bairro Anália Franco na cidade de São Paulo - SP.Com 3 dormitório(s), sendo 3 suite(s), 4 banheiro(s), 1 sala(s), 1 cozinha(s), 6 vagas(s) de garagem.Condições de Pagamento:Caracteristicas:Lazer:ChurrasqueiraPlay GroundPiscinaQuadra de TenisSoláriumSalão de Festa com Espaço GourmetSalão de FestasSalão de JogosSala de GinásticaSegurança:Cameras de VideosCerca ElétricaGuaritaPortão AutomáticoVigiaPortaria", 
"Link" : "https://www.vivareal.com.br/imovel/apartamento-3-quartos-vila-regente-feijo-zona-leste-sao-paulo-com-garagem-278m2-venda-RS2990000-id-1037226651/", 
"QtyRoomsMin" : 3.0, 
"QtyRoomsMax" : 3.0, 
"QtySuitesMin" : 3.0, 
"QtySuitesMax" : 3.0, 
"QtyParkingSlotMin" : 6.0, 
"QtyParkingSlotMax" : 6.0, 
"AreaMin" : 278.0, 
"AreaMax" : 278.0, 
"QtyBathroomsMin" : 4.0, 
"QtyBathroomsMax" : 4.0, 
"SiteOrigin" : NumberInt(3), 
"Type" : NumberInt(1), 
"Subtype" : NumberInt(7), 
"UpdateDate" : ISODate("2018-10-14T15:21:19.588+0000"), 
"SortOrder" : NumberInt(896), 
"IdDistrict" : NumberInt(42984), 
"DistrictName" : "Vila Regente Feijó", 
"IdCity" : NumberInt(9668), 
"CityName" : "São Paulo", 
"IdState" : NumberInt(26), 
"StateName" : "São Paulo", 
"UF" : "SP", 
"FullAddress" : "Rua José Alexandre Almeida Luiz", 
"ZipCode" : NumberInt(3337005), 
"Latitude" : null, 
"Longitude" : null, 
"ImageUrl" : "https://resizedimgs.vivareal.com/crop/360x240/vr.images.sp/2ddd2c0162262a0ab921fbac9b0ee072.jpg", 
"IdTransaction" : NumberInt(1), 
"ExpireAt" : ISODate("2018-10-29T15:21:19.588+0000"), 
"Facets" : [
    "Cozinha"
]
}
```

The result is something like this:

```
{
  Academia: 98473
  Espaço Verde / Parque: 93840
  Cozinha: 75934
}
```

My collection has 9M documents and this match finds 4M documents.

This query is taking 5 - 12s to return. It's awful :(

Is there any way to improve this?

In c# i have this :

```
var pipeline = this.Collection.Aggregate(new AggregateOptions { AllowDiskUse 
= true })
.Match(filter).SortBy(p=>p.SortOrder)
.Unwind<Property,object>(x => x.Facets)
.SortByCount<object>("$Facets");
List<FacetCount> listFacets = new List<FacetCount>();
var output = pipeline.ToList();
```

Same query in MongoDB:

```
aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "Subtype": {
        "$in": [
          7
        ]
      },
      "IdTransaction": 1,
      "IdCity": 9668
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "SortOrder": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$Facets"
  },
  {
    "$sortByCount": "$Facets"
  }
])
```

And here is what explain showed me.

```
{
  "stages": [
    {
      "$cursor": {
        "query": {
          "Subtype": {
            "$in": [
              7
            ]
          },
          "IdTransaction": 1,
          "IdCity": 9668
        },
        "fields": {
          "Facets": 1,
          "_id": 0
        },
        "queryPlanner": {
          "plannerVersion": 1,
          "namespace": "SonarImovel.Property",
          "indexFilterSet": false,
          "parsedQuery": {
            "$and": [
              {
                "IdCity": {
                  "$eq": 9668
                }
              },
              {
                "IdTransaction": {
                  "$eq": 1
                }
              },
              {
                "Subtype": {
                  "$eq": 7
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "winningPlan": {
            "stage": "FETCH",
            "inputStage": {
              "stage": "IXSCAN",
              "keyPattern": {
                "Subtype": 1,
                "IdTransaction": 1,
                "IdCity": 1,
                "AreaMax": 1
              },
              "indexName": "Query by City - Sort Area",
              "isMultiKey": false,
              "multiKeyPaths": {
                "Subtype": [

                ],
                "IdTransaction": [

                ],
                "IdCity": [

                ],
                "AreaMax": [

                ]
              },
              "isUnique": false,
              "isSparse": false,
              "isPartial": false,
              "indexVersion": 2,
              "direction": "forward",
              "indexBounds": {
                "Subtype": [
                  "[7.0, 7.0]"
                ],
                "IdTransaction": [
                  "[1.0, 1.0]"
                ],
                "IdCity": [
                  "[9668.0, 9668.0]"
                ],
                "AreaMax": [
                  "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "executionStats": {
            "executionSuccess": true,
            "nReturned": 1073562,
            "executionTimeMillis": 4049,
            "totalKeysExamined": 1073562,
            "totalDocsExamined": 1073562,
            "executionStages": {
              "stage": "FETCH",
              "nReturned": 1073562,
              "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 3507,
              "works": 1073563,
              "advanced": 1073562,
              "needTime": 0,
              "needYield": 0,
              "saveState": 8478,
              "restoreState": 8478,
              "isEOF": 1,
              "invalidates": 0,
              "docsExamined": 1073562,
              "alreadyHasObj": 0,
              "inputStage": {
                "stage": "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned": 1073562,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 1303,
                "works": 1073563,
                "advanced": 1073562,
                "needTime": 0,
                "needYield": 0,
                "saveState": 8478,
                "restoreState": 8478,
                "isEOF": 1,
                "invalidates": 0,
                "keyPattern": {
                  "Subtype": 1,
                  "IdTransaction": 1,
                  "IdCity": 1,
                  "AreaMax": 1
                },
                "indexName": "Query by City - Sort Area",
                "isMultiKey": false,
                "multiKeyPaths": {
                  "Subtype": [

                  ],
                  "IdTransaction": [

                  ],
                  "IdCity": [

                  ],
                  "AreaMax": [

                  ]
                },
                "isUnique": false,
                "isSparse": false,
                "isPartial": false,
                "indexVersion": 2,
                "direction": "forward",
                "indexBounds": {
                  "Subtype": [
                    "[7.0, 7.0]"
                  ],
                  "IdTransaction": [
                    "[1.0, 1.0]"
                  ],
                  "IdCity": [
                    "[9668.0, 9668.0]"
                  ],
                  "AreaMax": [
                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                  ]
                },
                "keysExamined": 1073562,
                "seeks": 1,
                "dupsTested": 0,
                "dupsDropped": 0,
                "seenInvalidated": 0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$unwind": {
          "path": "$Facets"
        }
      },
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": "$Facets",
          "count": {
            "$sum": {
              "$const": 1
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$sort": {
          "sortKey": {
            "count": -1
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "ok": 1
  }
```

And just to complete:

MY VM (On Azure)
Has 8GB
Running with SSD
Processor   Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2673 v4 @ 2.30GHz, 2295 Mhz, 1 Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s)

Comment: $size is not the case in my query becouse i want the count of each item inside my array.
So  -> Facet1 : 25600,   Facet2 : 12356
..
..

Comment: For completeness and avoiding misunderstanding, could you amend the original post to show, say, 3 docs that contain the Facet field?

Comment: Yep. Fixed original post

Comment: Thanks for adding the sample docs...clarifies so much. Anyway, performing this query over 4M matched docs is going to be slow. You should, however, be able to remove the intermediate `$sort` stage which should help some.

Comment: I already tried with and without sort :(

Comment: adding an index for Facets/SortOrder is not an option?

Answer (score 1):

The output of the explain plan shows that the query targetting is optimal. But the query is scanning a lot of documents as well which  requires IO. A covered query should improve the performance preventing the document scans, this means that no access to disk will be required. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query for details.

Additionally you may want to use an index for sorting and removing the sort stage. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/index.html.

Comment: Nothing yet :(
I added "Facets" column to my index trying to get the covered query like u said.
But nothing changed.

"executionTimeMillisEstimate": 13834

This is my query now:
aggregate([{ "$match" : { "Subtype" : { "$in" : [7] }, "IdTransaction" : 1, "IdCity" : 9668 } }, { "$unwind" : "$Facets" }, { "$sortByCount" : "$Facets" }])

I tried with a VM with 16gb and same result

Comment: If you are only interested in the Facets field I would recommend to add a project stage to select only the fields you are interested in, for example Facets and the fields you are matching on idCity, idTransaction, Subtype. Otherwise the index will need to include all the fields in the document to cover the query.

Comment: Additionally the index being used `Query by City - Sort Area` has no bounds on `AreaMax`: 

    "AreaMax": ["[MinKey, MaxKey]"]

This means that all keys need to be examined which is not optimal in terms of performance.